# Как добавить в конвертер ItemSource в SfDataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть SfDataGrid с привязкой `ItemSource = "{Binding Items}"`
Необходимо создать конвертер для изменения фона ячеек используя `MultiBinding`
Данный код работает для обычного `DataGrid`, а здесь в первом элементе выводит `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`. В чем можем быть проблема?

```
           <Style TargetType="Syncfusion:GridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myValidConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="ItemSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Syncfusion:SfDataGrid}}"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>


public class MaxConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Список, который присваивается в ItemSource выглядит так

```
public ObservableCollection<DisplayRobot> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set { _items = value; }
}
```

Comment: Это же коммерческий продукт, у них техподдержка быстрее вам ответит.

Comment: @aepot я бы небыл так уверен в техподдержке), был опыт когда чтобы задавать вопросы связанные с API необходимо было купить подписку. Одной подписки на продукт было мало)

Comment: @Aarnihauta у них нет бесплатной версии, триалка только. И поддержка должна влегкую пережевывать подобные вопросы, это их работа, иначе они ничего не продадут, если триалки поддерживать не станут.